# Ejecución de script para creación de procedimientos en uno solo para Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Tengo problema para unificar varios scripts en uno solo. Los scripts son creación de store procedure. Ejemplo:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "SP1"
.
.
.
END;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "SP2"
.
.
.
END;
```

Entonces al ejecutar, marca error:

```
PLS-00103 Encountered the symbol "CREATE"...
```

¿Cómo puedo unificarlos e indicar donde termina un SP y el otro?. He intentado con: Commit y /

Gracias de antemano

He intentado con: Commit y / pero marca error al encontrar el símbolo. Pretendo enviar un solo script para la ejecución de un lote y no una serie de archivos, gracias.

Estoy trabajando con SQL Developer, con PLSQL, gracias.

Comment: Usualmente el caracter `/` se utiliza en estos casos. Debe ir solo en una línea, después del último `end;` del SP, al menos en SQL*Plus, diría que SQL Developer debiera soportarlo de la misma manera.

Comment: Gracias, lo estaba haciendo de forma incorrecta. Reviso como cerrar la pregunta y marcar respuesta

Comment: Considero que la pregunta es válida y puede ser de ayuda a otros, dejé una respuesta para que no quede en comentarios. Veo que no has hecho el [tour], te invito a hacerlo y tener en cuenta [qué hacer si alguien te responde](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Un saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usualmente el caracter *slash* `/` se utiliza en estos casos en Oracle.

Es importante que dicho caracter debe ir solo, en una línea e indica al interprete que debe enviar la última porción del script al motor, antes de seguir leyendo y acumulando otra porción del mismo.

En tu caso, debiera ir después del último `end;` de cada procedimiento almacenado, es como funciona en SQL*Plus y diría que otras herramientas compatibles con Oracle, incluido SQL Developer debieran soportarlo de la misma manera.

Tomando tu ejemplo, debiera quedar algo como:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "SP1"
.
.
.
END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "SP2"
.
.
.
END;
/
```